# Terminating a shell script bar from a script foo.

Tags: shell-script, kill, background-process

I have a script `foo` which, if provided an argument `start`, starts, among other things a script `bar` in the background and exits - `bar` contains an infinite loop.

At a later stage, I want to call `foo`  with argument `stop` and I would like that script `bar`, which still runs in the background stops running.

What is the text book way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this the way init scripts normally do, when foo starts bar, you should write the PID of bar to a file named /var/run/bar (or similar location depending on your OS). Then when you call foo stop, you read the PID and signal the bar process appropriately. Of course there are other solutions, but this seems to be a "textbook" answer.